# Beautifulsoup pagination

Tags: python

am trying to run this code to run through multiple wikipedia pages yet am getting an error saying 
InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/wiki/[1799, 1799]_Football_League' (found at least ' '). Somebody help solve this error

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = [1888-89,1889-90]

for page in pages:
    source =urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+str(pages)+'_Football_League')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table',class_='wikitable sortable')



    rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for tr in rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two corrections to be made.

(1) The hyphen in 1889-89 is not an ordinary hyphen.
If you paste the URL, it will be below.
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1888%E2%80%9389_Football_League`

(2) The variable that joins the URLs is wrong.
str(pages) -> str(page)

```
pages = ['1888%E2%80%9389','1889%E2%80%9390']

source =urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+page+'_Football_League')
```